# Python Pandas with sqlalchemy | Bulk Insert Error

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pandas, sqlalchemy

I was try to Insert my millions of records from **CSV** File to **MySQL** Database, by using **Python** | **Pandas** with **sqlalchemy**. Some time this insertion is interrupted before the completion or not even insert single row to Database.

My Code is :

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('/home/shankar/LAB/Python/Rough/*******.csv')
# 2nd argument replaces where conditions is False
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None) 
df.head()
conn_str = "mysql+pymysql://root:MY_PASS@localhost/MY_DB?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0"
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
conn = engine.raw_connection()
df.to_sql(name='table_name', con=conn, 
      if_exists='append')
conn.close()
```

Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
 1563             else:
 -> 1564                 cur.execute(*args)
 1565             return cur

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
 164 
 --> 165         query = self.mogrify(query, args)
 166 

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in mogrify(self, query, args)
 143         if args is not None:
 --> 144             query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
 145 

 TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-6-bb91db9eb97e> in <module>()
 11 df.to_sql(name='company', con=conn, 
 12           if_exists='append',
 ---> 13           chunksize=10000)
 14 conn.close()

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
 1163         sql.to_sql(self, name, con, flavor=flavor, schema=schema,
 1164                    if_exists=if_exists, index=index, index_label=index_label,
 -> 1165                    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
 1166 
 1167     def to_pickle(self, path):

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
 569     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
 570                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
 --> 571                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
 572 
 573 

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
1659                             if_exists=if_exists, index_label=index_label,
1660                             dtype=dtype)
-> 1661         table.create()
1662         table.insert(chunksize)
1663 

/home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in create(self)
 688 
 689     def create(self):
 --> 690         if self.exists():
 691             if self.if_exists == 'fail':
 692                 raise ValueError("Table '%s' already exists." % self.name)

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in exists(self)
 676 
 677     def exists(self):
 --> 678         return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
 679 
 680     def sql_schema(self):

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in has_table(self, name, schema)
1674         query = flavor_map.get(self.flavor)
1675 
-> 1676         return len(self.execute(query, [name, ]).fetchall()) > 0
1677 
1678     def get_table(self, table_name, schema=None):

/home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
1574             ex = DatabaseError(
1575                 "Execution failed on sql '%s': %s" % (args[0], exc))
-> 1576             raise_with_traceback(ex)
1577 
1578     @staticmethod

/home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
 331         if traceback == Ellipsis:
 332             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
 --> 333         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
 334 else:
 335     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
1562                 cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
1563             else:
-> 1564                 cur.execute(*args)
1565             return cur
1566         except Exception as exc:

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
 163             pass
 164 
 --> 165         query = self.mogrify(query, args)
 166 
 167         result = self._query(query)

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in mogrify(self, query, args)
 142 
 143         if args is not None:
 --> 144             query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
 145 
 146         return query

  DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This error is Occurred in some sort of CSV files only.
Kindly notify my bug on this !

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the error raised your arguments in to the query aren't all strings so what you would have to do is go and convert each of the elements of data frame to string. `df =df.astype(str)`

Comment: I GET ERROR AS "name 'creaqte_engine' is not defined"



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-53ffd41daeb6> in <module>()
      7 df.head()
      8 conn_str = "mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/globalTracker?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0"
----> 9 engine = creaqte_engine(conn_str)
     10 conn = engine.raw_connection()
     11 # df =df.astype(str)

NameError: name 'creaqte_engine' is not defined

Comment: Just fix the typo - remove `q` from `crea*q*te_engine`